# Input type range, doesn't work on iPad app

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad

I have to implemented a slider into my iPad app. I was quit happy when I found input:

```
type="range"
```

in HTML5 specifications, but unfortunately that doesn't work on iPad.

I researched a subject and I found solution with jQuery UI, but jQuery is not allowed in my project. So I wonder if someone can suggest some other fix?

Comment: I should be more specific. Type range is working on iPad (iOS 7.1.1) web browser (Safari), but is not working in app that I developed with Dojo. When I try input type range from web example on W3SCHOOL is working fine. When I implemented the same line of code (without JS, just HTML) into my app it doesn't work.